# R: How to combine a normal boxplot with a grouped boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm trying to add a grouped boxplot into a boxplot with only one group. I already made it, but the problem is that I can't give a name to the boxplot that has only one group. It is simply not shown. The arguments "name" and "names" don't seem to work when your boxplot does not have different groups.

```
boxplot(Daten$NV,
        boxwex = 0.6, at = 1:1 - 0.2,col = "yellow",
        name = "Gesamtstichprobe",
        main = "Guinea Pigs' Tooth Growth",
        xlab = "Vitamin C dose mg",
        ylab = "tooth length",
        xlim = c(0.5, 3.5), ylim = c(0, 7), yaxs = "i")
boxplot(Daten$NV ~ Daten$CVKGruppe, add = TRUE,
        boxwex = 0.3, at = 1:3 + 0.3, col = "orange")
```

[image: Click here for Boxplot-Image]

Comment: Hi, could you make this more  [*reproducible*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038)?

Comment: Please share your data using something like `dput(yourdata)` or a subset of your data (i.e. `dput(yourdata[1:100,])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```r
boxplot( Daten$NV,
        boxwex = 0.6, at = 1:1 - 0.2, col = "yellow",
        name = "Gesamtstichprobe",
        main = "Guinea Pigs' Tooth Growth",
        xlab = "Vitamin C dose mg",
        ylab = "tooth length",
        xlim = c(0.5, 3.5), ylim = c(0, 7), yaxs = "i", xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = 0.8, labels = "Total")
boxplot(Daten$NV ~ Daten$CVKGruppe, add = TRUE,
        boxwex = 0.3, at = 1:3 + 0.3, col = "orange")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data**

```r
set.seed(1)
Daten <- data.frame(NV = rnorm(150, 4, 1),
  CVKGruppe = rep(c("Kamera aus", "Kamera ein_VH an", "Kamera eien_VH aus"),
                  each = 50))
```